# How to update a form based on a selected option?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to load an array of saved templates to be able to select from them as options in an ion-select and based on which option is chosen the form should be updated.

This is how my templates are composed:

```
    export interface Template {
 ...
  destination: string; //iban
  recipient: string;
  amount: number;
  reference: string;
}
```

And this is how my ion-select looks:

```
 <ion-item>
           <ion-label>Load template</ion-label>
           <ion-select (change)="this.transactionForm.patchValue({recipient: template.recipient, destination: template.destination, amount: template.amount, reference: template.reference})">
             <ion-option *ngFor = "let template of templates;">
               {{template.reference}}
             </ion-option>
           </ion-select>
         </ion-item>
```

The idea is to load the saved templates and choose one in the list so that the values in the form I'm filling get updated once you make your choice.

This is how I initialise the form in the constructor of the .ts file:

```
 constructor( public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public templateServicerino: TemplateService) {
    this.templateServicerino.createTemplate("DE365849", "John Johnson", 420, "Testerino");
    this.templates = this.templateServicerino.getAllTemplates();
    this.transactionForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          recipient: [''],
          destination: [''],
          amount: ['0'],
          reference:  ['']
        });
```

When I test this out I do get an option called "Testerino" when I click the select but once I press OK the form is not updated. My IDE says the field "template" in is unresolved

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You trying to access template reference outside the scope of an element. change method is not an ionic method.so refer this link https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/7807

More reference check ionic docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/

`<ion-item>
      <ion-label>Load template</ion-label>
      <ion-select  [(ngModel)]="selectObj" (ionChange)="onSelectChange($event,selectObj)" 
       >
      <ion-option *ngFor = "let template of templates;">
       {{template.reference}}
      </ion-option>
     </ion-select>
    </ion-item>`

past code in component after the constructor method.

```
 onSelectChange(selected:any,selectObj){
  console.log(selected,selectObj)
  this.transactionForm.patchValue({recipient: selectObj.recipient, destination: 
  selectObj.destination, amount: selectObj.amount, reference: selectObj.reference})
 }
```

Comment: At first it didn't let me because it was inside a Form, so I took that ion item out of the form. Now it doesn't crash, however the IDE says "unresolved variable or type selectObj" and the form still doesn't update when the option is selected

Comment: When using patchValue(), do you have to provide all the fields of the form you're going to change or only the ones you want to change?
for example if you're changing a form that has age, sex and location, do you need to change all 3 or can you just use patchvalue to change the age?

Comment: No need to change all the value. you can just do patchvalue to change the age that enough

Comment: Thank you, selectObj is still a problem though. Was that just a placeholder or an example or should I actually write selectObj? it says it's unresolved